# Rewriting URLs with htaccess, multiple parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to rewrite something like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/pages/article.html?id=1&title=Title-Goes-Here
```

into

```
https://mywebsite.com/pages/article/1/Title-Goes-Here
```

Using this Rewrite Rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ article.html?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

However, when I try this code in https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ it gives me

> This rule was not met.

Also tried it on my website htaccess file with no result. I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't create OR test rules on online sites, they are NOT trust worthy, so kindly test these rules into your localhost OR apache.

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess rules. Considering that you are hitting URL `https://mywebsite.com/pages/article.html?id=1&title=Title-Goes-Here` in browser AND you want to redirect it to URL `https://mywebsite.com/pages/article/1/Title-Goes-Here` in browser.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect in browser rules here....
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/]*)/([^.]*)\.html\?id=([^&]*)&title=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to html file rules here....
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$  $1/$2.html?id=$3&title=$4 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: I've found a workaround to my problem. I used my solution but moved the article.html page to the root folder, where htaccess was. Also, put <base href="/" /> right after <head> element because none of the CSS or javascript were loading. Thank you for taking the time to give me an answer. I will also try this. This was bugging me for the last 2 days.

Comment: @cat15ets, sure please do check once, its tested in my localhost suceesfully, let me know how it goes.

Comment: It works, but the page reloads every second, and the new content is added to the bottom. Don't know why it gives me this behavior.

Comment: @cat15ets, this considers hat you are hitting URL `https://mywebsite.com/pages/article.html?id=1&title=Title-Goes-Here` in browser AND you want to redirect it to URL `https://mywebsite.com/pages/article/1/Title-Goes-Here` in browser. Please do let me know if this is right assumptions?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. The problem is that when using your code, the page loads every second, adding content to the previous one

Comment: @cat15ets, I have edited my rules now; please test edited rules once, please make sure that you have your htaccess file along side in your pages folder(not inside it), this is working well for me. Also kindly make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: I'm testing in private, the new url format works, but the page reloads every second. htaccess is in root(main folder), it's not inside pages folder

Comment: @cat15ets, hmmm these rules work fine for me. So do you have any other htaccess file OR any other rules in your same this htaccess apart from these?

Comment: No, I've commented the previous rules

Comment: @cat15ets, ok could you please try changing last line FROM `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$` TO `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$` once and test it once please; after clearing cache.

Comment: It works. After I put<base href="/" /> right after <head> element, The page doesn't reloads and all works as intended. Thank you!!